# Super Sub menu Not appearing like supposed to

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So I was trying to make a Super sub-menu and for some reason, the super sub-menu appears when I hover above the main menus, not the sub-menus. and I thought something is wrong with the display: none; but I don't know how to fix it. I already tried to put it with the class it still didn't work and I already double-check the HTML to ensure not typo and none so I'm so confused and stuck right now, PLEASE HELP.

The code :

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
body {
  background-image: url(photo-1542831371-29b0f74f9713.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
  
nav {
  /* this is a tag */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  display:flex;
}
  
nav a {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 55px;
  padding: 2.3px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;  
}

nav form {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
  
nav ul {
  display:flex;
  list-style: none;
    
}
  
nav li:hover>a {
  background: rgb(224, 224, 224);
  cursor: pointer;
}
  
nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 238, 238, 0.89);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}
  
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
  
nav ul li ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -ms-transform: translate(100%,0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(100%,0);
  transform:translate(100%,0);
  list-style: none;
}



.subMenu li:hover>.SuperSubMenu{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Wall of nothing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <form name="" method="" action="BUTTON%20TEST.html">
      <input type="image" name="IB1" src="gradient-coding-logo-template_23-2148809439.jpg" width="70" height="60">
    </form>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="about.php">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="about.php#expectations">Expectations</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about.php#faq">FAQ</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="laptopprogram.php">Laptop Program</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="why.php">Why?</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">What?</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Events & Activities</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Meet The Grads</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Events</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Opportunities</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">asd</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" target="_blank">assd</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
        <ul class="subMenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Numbers</a>
            <ul class="SuperSubMenu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Person1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Person2</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          
          <li>
            <a href="#">Fax</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `not working` is barely a good description. How is it not working? what is expected, what happens instead?

Comment: is it better now @tacoshy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use direct descendant operators in your third-to-last CSS rule - the one which makes regular sub menus appear when hovering the main menu items. Otherwise this rule will also affect (i.e. make visible) the `ul` of the SuperSubMenus on hover of the main menu items. So change this selector:

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

...to the following:

```
nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
body {
  background-image: url(photo-1542831371-29b0f74f9713.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
  
nav {
  /* this is a tag */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  display:flex;
}
  
nav a {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 55px;
  padding: 2.3px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;  
}

nav form {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
  
nav ul {
  display:flex;
  list-style: none;
    
}
  
nav li:hover>a {
  background: rgb(224, 224, 224);
  cursor: pointer;
}
  
nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 238, 238, 0.89);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}
  
nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
  
nav ul li ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -ms-transform: translate(100%,0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(100%,0);
  transform:translate(100%,0);
  list-style: none;
}


.subMenu li:hover>.SuperSubMenu{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Wall of nothing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <form name="" method="" action="BUTTON%20TEST.html">
      <input type="image" name="IB1" src="gradient-coding-logo-template_23-2148809439.jpg" width="70" height="60">
    </form>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="about.php">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="about.php#expectations">Expectations</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about.php#faq">FAQ</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="laptopprogram.php">Laptop Program</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="why.php">Why?</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">What?</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Events & Activities</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Meet The Grads</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Events</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Opportunities</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">asd</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" target="_blank">assd</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
        <ul class="subMenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Numbers</a>
            <ul class="SuperSubMenu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Person1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Person2</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          
          <li>
            <a href="#">Fax</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer works thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

is overwriting

```
.SuperSubMenu {
 display: none; 
}
```

property.
To fix it you can add !important to both css for SuperSubMenu. This isn't probably the best way, but it works.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
body {
  background-image: url(photo-1542831371-29b0f74f9713.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
  
nav {
  /* this is a tag */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  display:flex;
}
  
nav a {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 55px;
  padding: 2.3px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;  
}

nav form {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
  
nav ul {
  display:flex;
  list-style: none;
    
}
  
nav li:hover>a {
  background: rgb(224, 224, 224);
  cursor: pointer;
}
  
nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 238, 238, 0.89);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}

.SuperSubMenu {
  display: none !important;
}
  
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
  
nav ul li ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -ms-transform: translate(100%,0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(100%,0);
  transform:translate(100%,0);
  list-style: none;
}

.subMenu li:hover>.SuperSubMenu{
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Wall of nothing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <form name="" method="" action="BUTTON%20TEST.html">
      <input type="image" name="IB1" src="gradient-coding-logo-template_23-2148809439.jpg" width="70" height="60">
    </form>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="about.php">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="about.php#expectations">Expectations</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about.php#faq">FAQ</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="laptopprogram.php">Laptop Program</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="why.php">Why?</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">What?</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Events & Activities</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Meet The Grads</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Events</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Opportunities</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">asd</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" target="_blank">assd</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
        <ul class="subMenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Numbers</a>
            <ul class="SuperSubMenu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Person1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Person2</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          
          <li>
            <a href="#">Fax</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your solution also works! but can you tell me the details of how this !important works?

Comment: @GrandLineRookie , with !important you force css to ovewrite other overlapping properties, but in some circunstances it's "dangerous" because you could find yourself using it in a never ending loop. Anyway, for your problem this works, but the solution from Johannes is better than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do with simple CSS

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown Menu</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I'm asking, the problem here is the Super Sub-Menu appear when I hover above the main menu, which is supposed to only appear when I hover above the submenu

Comment: yeah it is same concept. you just separate your elements with different ID or Classe.